# I need to create a new variable in my dataset. it is defined by conditions of two existing variables in r

Tags: r

this is what i have

```
total2 %>%
  mutate(happiness = case_when(GDP > 17300 ~ "happy",
                               Mortality < 29 ~ "happy"))
```

and this is the mistake

```
‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: It looks like you Mortality column is a factor. if you add `summary(total2)` and create a reproducible example, that would help

Comment: When you fix the `factor` problem, then you can remove `case_when` and instead just use `mutate(happy = GDP > 17300 | Mortality < 29)` (for a logical ... or `mutate(happiness = if_else(GDP > 17300 | Mortality < 29, "happy", "unhappy"))` if you really want strings).

Comment: Try this might works for your problrm ```total2$happiness <- ifelse(total2$GDP>17300 & total2$Mortality < 29,"happy","Unhappy") ```